# Thor CLI: Setting a custom order of commands in help output

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

The [thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor) gem seems to always order the defined commands alphabetically when printing its help output. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "z", "this should go first"
  def z; end

  desc "a", "this should go second"
  def a; end
end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

Saving this script as `thor-test` and calling it without arguments gives this output:

```
Commands:
  thor-test a               # this should go second
  thor-test help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
  thor-test z               # this should go first
```

**Question:** How can I tell Thor to order the entries differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as if Thor doesn't offer a configuration option for this. So I'll settle on some monkey-patching for now. [aristotll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718959/3449673) pointed me to the right place in Thor's [source code](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/0211fd443238c83f332b3124b375c75151167025/lib/thor.rb#L195).

But instead of hacking the `<=>` method, I decided to change the implementation of the `help` method. This seems still cleaner to me and has the advantage that I can further influence the behavior of the help output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  class << self
    def help(shell, subcommand = false)
      list = printable_commands(true, subcommand)
      Thor::Util.thor_classes_in(self).each do |klass|
        list += klass.printable_commands(false)
      end

      # Remove this line to disable alphabetical sorting
      # list.sort! { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }

      # Add this line to remove the help-command itself from the output
      list.reject! {|l| l[0].split[1] == 'help'}

      if defined?(@package_name) && @package_name
        shell.say "#{@package_name} commands:"
      else
        shell.say "Commands:"
      end

      shell.print_table(list, :indent => 2, :truncate => true)
      shell.say
      class_options_help(shell)

      # Add this line if you want to print custom text at the end of your help output.
      # (similar to how Rails does it)
      shell.say 'All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.'
    end
  end

  desc "z", "this should go first"
  def z; end

  desc "a", "this should go second"
  def a; end
end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `help` [source code](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/0211fd443238c83f332b3124b375c75151167025/lib/thor.rb#L195)

```
list.sort! { |a, b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
```

It is sorted alphabetically as expected.

---

Of course evil monkey patch is always allowed, add the following code before `MyCLI`.

```
SCRIPT = File.basename $PROGRAM_NAME
class String
  alias old_compare <=>
  # @param [String]  other_string
  # @return [Fixnum]
  def <=>(other_string)
    # currently the command name is like `script_name+space+usage`
    # a monkey patch to make z goes first
    if other_string.start_with?(SCRIPT)
      index = SCRIPT.size + 1
      if other_string[index] == 'z'
        return 1
      elsif self[index] =='z'
        return -1
      end
    end
    old_compare other_string
  end
end
```

The output:

```
Commands:
  thor-test z               # this should go first
  thor-test a               # this should go second
  thor-test help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
```

Comment: Your monkey patch is a bit too evil for me ;) I posted my own solution and will accept that for now. But big thanks for pointing me to the right place in the source code.